# Accessing Resources IDs using Kotlin & Anko

Tags: kotlin, anko

I am new to Android/Kotlin/Anko and I have a question regarding the way to access color (and probably other) resources from within Anko.

I know that there are helpers like `textResource` where you simply pass the `R.string.my_color` to simplify the process of setting resource strings but how about accessing colors using the `Resources` instance from the `View` class ?

Let’s say you have a subclass of `Button` and want to change the text color. If you use the `textResource` it will change the text string not the color, and if you use `textColor` then you must specify the real resource ID by using `resources.getColor(R.color.my_color, null)` which wouldn't be so annoying if you didn't have to pass the optional theme parameter (`null` here)

Is creating an extension on `Resources` useful here ?

```
fun Int.fromResources(resources: Resources): Int {
    return resources.getColor(this, null)
}
```

What is the recommended way ?

**EDIT**

I changed the `textColor` value extension to do just that, which I found the cleanest thing to do except I have no idea if this is really *Android* friendly

```
var android.widget.TextView.textColor: Int
    get() = throw AnkoException("'android.widget.TextView.textColor' property does not have a getter")
    set(v) = setTextColor(resources.getColor(v, null))
```

Comment: I suggest using `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_id)` instead  `resources.getColor(v, null)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a property extension like this one instead of the one you suggested:

```
var TextView.textColorRes: Int
    get() = throw PropertyWithoutGetterException("textColorRes")
    set(@ColorRes v) = setTextColor(resources.getColor(v, null))
```

Or use `ContextCompat` as suggested by Damian Petla:

```
var TextView.textColorRes: Int
    get() = throw PropertyWithoutGetterException("textColorRes")
    set(@ColorRes v) = setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, v))
```

You should keep Anko's `textColor`:

- Allows you to set a color directly without taking it from XML, if needed at some point
- Prevents you from importing the wrong `textColor` (Anko's one or yours), same property names with different behaviour is not a good idea.